# Запуск на WebMatrix  yii2

Tags: yii2, php

Можно ли разрабатывать и запустить на webmatrix сайты на yii фреймворке? Интересует именно практический опыт использования, ссылки на дельные ресурсы по этому поводу.

Comment: @LutiyCsharp, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Нет нельзя. Вебматрикс это лишь обычный статический конструктор страниц. Как раньше был Narod.ru

Comment: Не пожалейте 150 р в месяц и купите полноценный сервер netangels.ru